# using import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag in Junit 4

Tags: junit, junit4, junit5

I have to use import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;

my project is in eclipse 4.18, and I am not able to migrate it to eclipse 4.19 . and is written in junit 4.
I need to use the @Tag annotation
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag; does not work in my project on eclipse 4.18 and junit 4, and causes compilation errors

how else can I use @Tag or something similar in eclipse 4.18 and junit 4, what import should I use?

I have to give some annotation similar to @Tag from import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;what can I use a similar in junit4 and Eclipse 4.18?

Comment: What do you mean by „I have to use import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag“? What requires that?

Comment: I have to give some annotation similar to @Tag from  import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;what can I use a similar in junit4 and Eclipse 4.18?